# How to instantiate only part of a function template if a condition is true

Tags: c++, templates, conditional-statements, if-constexpr

Is it possible to build only some part of the code given the type of the template in C++ ?
It would be something lake that :

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
void printType(T param)
{
    #if T == char*
        cout << "char*" << endl;
    #elif T == int
        cout << "int" << endl;
    #else
        cout << "???" << endl;
    #endif
}

int main()
{
    printType("Hello world!");
    printType(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Since C++17 there is a way to do exactly this with if-constexpr. The following compiles since clang-3.9.1, gcc-7.1.0, and recent MSVC compiler 19.11.25506 handles well too with an option /std:c++17.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
void printType(T)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, const char*>)
        std::cout << "const char*" << std::endl;
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int>)
        std::cout << "int" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "???" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    printType("Hello world!");
    printType(1);
    printType(1.1);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
const char*
int
???
```

Comment: Thanks! fixed and tested. This is actually more powerful, see the related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28075962/1906174. In that situation code won't compile without constexpr

Comment: Just be aware that there is a difference between `T=char*` and `T=const char*`.  You might need to utilize `std::remove_cv_t` to handle both

Answer (score 58):

Type traits:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits> // C++0x
//#include <tr1/type_traits> // C++03, use std::tr1

template<typename T>
void printType(T param)
{
  if(std::is_same<T,char*>::value)
        std::cout << "char*" << endl;
  else if(std::is_same<T,int>::value)
        std::cout << "int" << endl;
  else
        std::cout << "???" << endl;
}
```

Or even better yet, just overload the function:

```
template<class T>
void printType(T partam){
  std::cout << "???" << endl;
}

void printType(char* partam){
  std::cout << "char*" << endl;
}

void printType(int partam){
  std::cout << "int" << endl;
}
```

Partial ordering will take care that the correct function is called. Also, overloading is preferred to template specialization in the general case, see [this](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm) and [this artice](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/049.htm) for why. Might not apply for you if you totally have to print the type, as implicit conversions are considered for overloaded functions.

Comment: +1 for presenting both alternative (and referring to Sutter's take on template specialization). I will note that the second approach is "better" because more extensible. Notably, for custom types, ADL requires the second approach.

Comment: @Matthieu: Yes, but as I said, it might not apply if one is strictly interested in the type, as implicit conversions could be involved. Or is it ambigious if you have both implicit conversion and a fallback template available?

Comment: if an implicit conversion is required, then I think the template function would be a better match. I have some difficulties with the rules for function selection and the conversion sequences :)

Comment: Note that in the first example `std::is_same<T,char*>::value` won't handle string literals like `"Hello world!"` since they would decay into `const char*` instead of `char*`, and in the second example `void printType(char* partam)` won't accept string literals either. So you should consider using `std::remove_cv<T>::type` in the first example, and `const char*` in the second example

Answer (score 10):

Use template specialization:

```
template<typename T>
void printType(T param)
{
   // code for the general case - or omit the definition to allow only the specialized types
}

template<>
void printType<char*>(char* param)
{
   // code for char*
}

template<>
void printType<int>(int param)
{
   // code for int    
}

// ...
```

Comment: Herb Sutter recommend *not* to use template specialization (on functions) and to simply use regular overload. See http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm

Answer (score 6):

You can use a specialization. The preprocessor runs before all templates and cannot interact with them.

```
template<typename T> void printType(T t) {
    std::cout << typeid(T).name(); // fallback
}
template<> void printType<char*>(char* ptr) {
    std::cout << "char*";
}
template<> void printType<int>(int val) {
    std::cout << "int";
}
```

Comment: Herb Sutter recommend not to use template specialization (on functions) and to simply use regular overload. See http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm

Comment: @Matthieu: I don't give a crap what Sutter recommends. My code solves the OP's problem, even if he doesn't take any arguments. Overloading definitely does not.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation with the preprocessor.

Comment: WoW! Let's be cool :) Overloading *definitely* solves the problem, as demonstrated by Xeo. The issue with specialization is that if you were (suddenly) to introduce a `template <typename T> void printType(T* t);` overload *after the `char*` specialization*, then `char *c; printType(c);` would call this new overload rather than the "intuitively expected" specialization: http://ideone.com/F1xS7

Answer (score 4):

You use [template specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5w1yety%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to specify versions of your function to work differently based on its type. For example, you can make a generic version of a function that would work with most types, and make a specific version for e.g. `int` that will be faster. You'd do it this way:

```
template <class T>
void printType(T param)
{
    cout<<"Generic version"<<endl;
}
template <>
void printType<int>(int param)
{
    cout<<"Int version"<<endl;
}
template <>
void printType<char>(char param)
{
    cout<<"Char version"<<endl;
}
//Rince and repeat.
```

Comment: Herb Sutter recommend not to use template specialization (on functions) and to simply use regular overload. See http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm