# Unexplained inability to compare string in C++ within templates

Tags: c++, string, templates

I'm getting the standard

> error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

error. However, I have included `string`, and there is no apparent way for me to explain this.

Here is my code.

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

// [...]
template <typename T>
class Graph {
private:
    // [...]
    struct Vertex {
        T name;
        // [...]
    };
    std::vector<Vertex> verts;
public:
    // [...]
    template <typename P>
    int vertex(P item) {
        if (std::is_same<P,T>::value) {
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < verts.size(); i++){
                if (verts[i].name == item) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
        } else if (std::is_same<P,int>::value) {
            return item;
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

The compiler is VS2012, the platform is Windows 8.1 64bit.

Comment: If `P` is not a string, your code will fail.  C++ is not a dynamic language - your code is evaluated at compile time.  You make provisions for the case when `P` is an `int` - indicating you expect that possibility.  But in that case, your code will fail to compile, because you're still comparing it with a string.

Comment: I was under the impression from [This SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6251889/type-condition-in-template) that C++ can switch branches at compile time based on inference.

Comment: @PythonNut, `if` makes a decision at runtime. It's not conditional compilation. The condition, in this case, is a compile-time value, but it's still used during runtime.

Comment: So is the code in the linked question invalid? Basically `P`, my method is completely wrong? I was hoping `std` could pull off some magic with macros or something... oh well.

Comment: No, C++ will not switch branches with runtime `if`.  You need to use meta-programming facilities like `std::enable_if` to do what you're trying to accomplish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you just need two `vertex` methods, like this (no template):

```
int vertex(const T& item) {
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < verts.size(); i++){
    if (verts[i].name == item) {
      return i;
    }
  }
}

int vertex(int item) {
  return item;
}
```

That won't work if `T` turns out to be `int`, but that doesn't seem likely to work with your original code either.

The above also fails to implement the default `vector(SomeOtherType)` case as returning a default -1. It will just fail to compile, which to me seems reasonable. YMMV.

Comment: I turns out this and some template parameter inference does exactly what I had in mind originally. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Making an educated guess, in `if (verts[i].name == item)` it seems that `verts[i].name` has been instantiated as a `std::string` while `item` hasn't been instantiated as a `std::string`. Thus, the compiler rightfully complains that there's no overloaded operator to compare a `std::string` against `X`.

### Update:

Another guess is that `X` is being instantiated as an `int` or a `double` because if it was instantiated as a `std::string` the compiler would complain about attempting to convert a `std::string` to an `int` by returning it in `Graph::vertex()` member function.

Comment: `verts[i]` is of type `Vertex`, but `verts[i].name` is likely of type `std::string`

Comment: Very sorry, edited Question to specify the structure of Vertex.

Comment: I'm not sure this argument still applies... as both the LHS and RHS are of type `std::string`.