# V8 Javascript engine: v8::Arguments and function templates

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, v8, embedded-v8

I wrapped a C++ standard library `std::map<T1,T2>` that I want to expose as a Node.JS addon. I want to have two functions, `Set` for adding a new value to the hash table, and `Get` for looking up value from the map. I want a single function that would work for "arbitrary" type. This means `Get` would have to extract value of type `T1` from `Args[0]` (note that `Args` is of type `v8::Arguments`). See the code below.

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
class Hash : public node::ObjectWrap {
public:
    static v8::Persistent<v8::FunctionTemplate> constructor;
    static void Init(v8::Handle<v8::Object> target);
protected:
    /* ... */
    static v8::Handle<v8::Value> New(const v8::Arguments& Args); // new object 
    static v8::Handle<v8::Value> Set(const v8::Arguments& Args); // set H[x]=y
    static v8::Handle<v8::Value> Get(const v8::Arguments& Args); // return H[x]
private:
    std::map<T1, T2> H;
};
/* ... */
template<typename T1, typename T2>
v8::Handle<v8::Value> Hash<T1, T2>::Get(const v8::Arguments& Args) {
    v8::HandleScope HandleScope;

    THash<T1, T2>* H = ObjectWrap::Unwrap<Hash<T1, T2> >(Args.This());
    // TODO: I want to extract argument Args[0] of type T1, call it x, and then
    // return argument y=H->get(x) of type T2.
    return v8::Undefined();
}
```

Is there a way to do this? If yes, what is *the* way of doing it?

In case there is no way of extracting an arbitrary type, what is the best practice in case I am willing to restrict to several predefined types? For example, `T=int`, `T=std::string`, `T=MyType1`, and `T=MyType2`.

Comment: What happens when you try `T1 x = *(T1 *)Args[0];`?

Comment: @AustinMullins: You crash because V8 doesn't store strings the same way as `std::string` does. Most likely, this won't even work correctly for integers - and even if it does, you've just exploited an implementation detail that you cannot rely on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need helper functions that will convert from `T1` and `T2` to `v8::Value` and vice versa. The problem is, this conversion is type-specific so you won't get around type traits or overloaded functions for each type as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6251916/785541). Something like this should work:

```
#include <type_traits> // C++0x

template<typename T>
T fromV8Value(v8::Handle<v8::Value> value)
{
  if (std::is_same<T,std::string>::value)
  {
    v8::String::Utf8Value stringValue(value);
    return std::string(*stringValue, stringValue.length());
  }
  else if (std::is_same<T,int>::value)
    return value->IntegerValue();
  else
    throw new std::exception("Unsupported type");
}

v8::Handle<v8::Value> toV8Value(std::string& value)
{
  return v8::String::New(value.c_str(), value.length());
}

v8::Handle<v8::Value> toV8Object(int value)
{
  return v8::Number::New(value);
}

...

v8::Handle<v8::Value> Hash::Set(const v8::Arguments& Args)
{
  T1 key = fromV8Value<T1>(Args[0]);
  T2 value = fromV8Value<T2>(Args[1]);
  return ...;
}

v8::Handle<v8::Value> Hash::Get(const v8::Arguments& Args)
{
  T1 key = fromV8Value<T1>(Args[0]);
  T2 value = ...;
  return toV8Object(value);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought the answer to my first question should be "no". The solution with type traits that you suggest looks okay to me. Thanks. Just of curiosity, do V8 people usually go this way about this? (I mean, is this considered ``good practice''?)

Comment: Also, can I avoid using standard library's `std::is_same`?

Comment: @blazs: I have no idea how V8 people go about this - I've never seen code doing anything similar in V8. As to `std::is_same` - what's the problem with it? If you are concerned that the multiple `if` statements will be slow - the compiler will optimize them away. I'm not aware of any better solutions. Function overloading could work here as well, but you would have to work with out parameters.

Comment: I'm not worried about compiler not optimizing it or anything like that. It's just that I've been using V8 with internal library that doesn't use C++'s standard library and including it (stdlib) just for the purpose of conversion between V8 types seems an overkill.

Comment: @blazs: V8 itself uses stdlib.