# Conditional compilation based on template values?

Tags: c++, templates

the question posed in:
[Type condition in template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6251889/type-condition-in-template)

is very similar, yet the original question wasn't quite answered.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <type_traits>


class AA {
public:
    double a;

    double Plus(AA &b) {
        return a + b.a;
    }
};

template<class T> double doit(T &t) {
    if (std::is_same<T, AA>::value)
        return t.Plus(t);
    else
        return t + t;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    double a;
    AA aa;

    doit(a);
    doit(aa);

    return 0;
}
```

This doesn't compile, nor did I expect it to.  Is something like this possible?  Being, based on the template value, I want some code to be compiled, and others not.  Here, 'double' doesn't have a method called "Plus" and class "AA" doesn't override the '+' operator.  Operator overloading isn't always desirable when considering subtle semantics to the operations, so I'm looking for an alternative.  I'd prefer to do #ifdef's (truly conditional compilation as posed in the ref'd question), but based on template values.

Comment: I found [this](https://blog.tartanllama.xyz/if-constexpr); I really like it.

Answer (score 14):

Since C++17 there is static if which is called if-constexpr. The following compiles fine since clang-3.9.1 and gcc-7.1.0, latest MSVC compiler 19.11.25506  handles  well too with an option /std:c++17.

```
template<class T> double doit(T &t) {
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, AA>)
        return t.Plus(t);
    else
        return t + t;
}
```

Comment: Gawd I hate if this is the only option. I need an additional argument to my constructor if the template type if of a certain type. I'll take your word for it that the compiler only compiles one version of this code, but it looks like a typical `if` statement, and you certainly can't use it to wrap functions.

Comment: @JonathanWood https://stackoverflow.com/a/37048889/1599699

Answer (score 5):

What you want is a static if. C++ doesn't have it. There are many ways to work around it, none as good as native support. In addition to the methods specified in the other two answers, you could try tag dispatch.

```
template<class T> double doitImpl(T &t, std::true_type) {
    return t.Plus(t);
}

template<class T> double doitImpl(T &t, std::false_type) {
    return t+t;
}

template<class T> double doit(T &t) {
    return doitImpl(t, std::is_same<T, AA>);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I think I like this solution the best.  The static if would be the ideal approach.  You see, this is a dumbed-down version of the bigger problem, where I have 4 specializations which would need to use one variation of the code, and 4 specializations which would need the 2nd variation of the code.  This solution lets me have one implementation in the code base for each varation.

Comment: Came here with the same question in mind. This answer fits best. Thanks! Would really like to see it as an accepted one

Comment: More research on the topic shows we have if-constexpr since c++17. Added an answer for that

Answer (score 3):

```
double doit(AA &t) {
  return t.Plus(t);;
}
template<class T> double doit(T &t) {
  return t + t;
}
```

Your code doesn't work because if the template is deduced as `AA` then `t +  t` inside the body is ill-formed. On the other hand if `T` is deduces as `double` then `t.Plus(t)` becomes ill-formed.

To better understand what is happening:
A template is instantiated for each template  type is called with.

`doIt(a)` instantiates `doIt` with `T = double`:

```
double doIt<double>(double &t) {
  if (false)
     return t.Plus(t);  // <-- syntax error
  else
    return t + t;
}
```

`doIt(aa)` instantiates `doIt` with `T = AA`:

```
double doIt<AA>(AA &t) {
  if (true)
    return t.Plus(t);
  else 
    return t + t;   // <-- syntax error
}
```

---

You should **avoid specializing function templates** because **functions overload**. You can read this excellent Herb Sutter article: [Why Not Specialize Function Templates?](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm)

Answer (score 3):

Overloading?

```
template<class T>
double doit(T &t) {
    return t + t;
}

double doit(AA &t) {
    return t.Plus(t);
}
```

Explicit specialization is also possible, though superfluous:

```
template<class T>
double doit(T &t) {
    return t + t;
}

template<>
double doit<>(AA &t) {
    return t.Plus(t);
}
```

Comment: Actually, the specialization doesn't work like you'd expect: http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm

Comment: @RazvanCojocaru Any particular reason you posted this comment? It works quite like I would expect, as I am aware of the peculiarities surrounding explicit specializations. And it works just as intended in this case.

Comment: The code won't work with the tiniest modifications. The Sutter article explains it. E.g., the following code prints out "base template": `#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct X {};

template<class T>
void doit(T)
{
    cout << "base template\n";
}

template<>
void doit<>(X&)
{
    cout << "full specialization\n";
}

int main()
{
    X x;
    doit(x);
}
`

Comment: @RazvanCojocaru You literally just changed the meaning of `doit` without adjusting the meaning of the explicit specialization accordingly. That's a load of nonsense.

Answer (score 2):

This code compiles and runs:

```
#include <boost/type_traits/is_floating_point.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits/is_class.hpp>
#include <boost/utility/enable_if.hpp>

using namespace boost;

class AA {
public:
    double a;

    AA Plus(AA &b) {
        AA _a;
        _a.a = a + b.a;
        return _a;
    }
};


template<class T>
typename disable_if<is_floating_point<T>, T >::type
doit(T &t) {
    return t.Plus(t);
}


template<class T>
typename enable_if<is_floating_point<T>, T >::type
doit(T &t) {
    return t+t;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    double a;
    AA aa;

    doit(a);
    doit(aa);

    return 0;
}
```