# Can C++ templates be used for conditional code inclusion?

Tags: c++, templates

So that:

```
template <bool Mode>
void doIt()
{
   //many lines
   template_if(Mode)
   {
      doSomething(); // and not waste resources on if
   }
   //many other lines
}
```

I know there is enable_if command that can be used for enabling the function conditionally, but I do not think I can use it such option here.
Essentially what I need is template construct that acts as #ifdef macro.

Comment: they arent meant to work like that

Comment: In C++17, you can say `if constexpr (Mode) { /* ... */ }`.

Comment: you can use policy based design for this, have another class (which actually calls `doSomething()` and only call `doSomething()` in specialized version of whatever `Mode` is

Comment: why not? functions can be enabled and disabled depending on template parameters - how is that different?

Comment: @DraifKroneg: You seem to be expecting C++ to make sense :P

Comment: Any decent compiler will optimize out `if(Mode)` in release builds. The question is if you need `doSomething` to be compilable when `Mode` is false.

Comment: I found [this](https://blog.tartanllama.xyz/if-constexpr); I really like it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Before trying something complex it's often worth checking if the simple solution already achieves what you want.

The simplest thing I can think of is to just use an `if`:

```
#include <iostream>

void doSomething()
{
  std::cout << "doing it!" << std::endl;
}

template <bool Mode>
void doIt()
{
   //many lines
   if(Mode)
   {
      doSomething(); // and not waste resources on if
   }
   //many other lines
}

void dont()
{
  doIt<false>();
}

void actuallyDoIt()
{
  doIt<true>();
}
```

So what does that give:

[gcc 5.3 with no optimizations](https://godbolt.org/g/sUgd7y) enabled gives:

```
void doIt<false>():
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    nop
    popq    %rbp
    ret
void doIt<true>():
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    call    doSomething()
    nop
    popq    %rbp
    ret
```

Note no `doSomething()` call in the `false` case just the bare work of the `doIt` function call. Turning optimizations on would eliminate even that.
So we already get what we want and are not wasting anything in the `if`. It's probably good to leave it at that rather than adding any unneeded complexity.

Answer (score 1):

You could specialize your template so that your code is only used when the template parameter is `true`:

```
template < typename _Cond > struct condition {};

template <> struct condition<false> {
    static /* constexpr */ void do_something() {};
}

template <> struct condition<true> {
    static void do_something() {
      // Actual code
    }
}

// Usage:
condition<true>::do_something();
condition<compiletime_constant>::do_something();
```

Comment: Why? This will even prevent the code from being compiled

Comment: Recommending macros... and I don't think you really grokked the purpose of the question. `Mode` is a template argument, not a macro definition.

Comment: Removed the last paragraph :P I don't see whats wrong with the template based solution though

Comment: That part's fine :) (or as fine as it can be in C++ anyway!)

Comment: @tobspr: 'This will even prevent the code from being compiled' - not quite.  The code must parse as valid template code, even if it's never instantiated.

Comment: Can you explain what's going on here please? What is `condition`? What does `<>` mean? How are you defining `condition<false>` - how does that work? Can I use this e.g. in a `class` to have template-optional members?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28076655/1599699 https://stackoverflow.com/a/28198279/1599699

Answer (score 1):

It can *sort of* be done.

If the code inside your "if" is syntactically and semantically valid for the full set of template arguments that you intend to provide, then you can basically just write an `if` statement. Thanks to basic optimisations, `if (someConstant) { .. }` is not going to survive compilation when `someConstant` is `false`. And that's that.

However, if the conditional code is actually *not valid* when the condition isn't met, then you can't do this. That's because class templates and function templates are instantiated ... *in full*. Your entire function body is instantiated so it all has to be valid. There's no such thing as instantiating an arbitrary block of code.<sup>†</sup>

So, in that case, you'd have to go back to messy old function specialisation with `enable_if` or whatever.

---

<sup><sup>†</sup> C++17 is likely to have `if constexpr` which essentially gives you exactly this. But that's future talk.</sup>

Comment: "There's no such thing as instantiating an arbitrary block of code.†" -- what about polymorphic lambdas in C++14?

Comment: [It does](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1c1dfc32fbdcf5e0), but requires some boilerplate to make the expressions dependent.

Comment: @melak47: Ahahaha "some boilerplate" :P