# Templated class: Check if complex at compile time

Tags: c++, templates, complex-numbers

I have a class `A` templated with a `Scalar` which can be real- or complex-valued. It has a method `realPart` which is supposed to return the real part of the number. If `Scalar` is real-valued, it should just return the original Scalar, and `.real()` if it's of complex type.

When writing

```cpp
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>

template<class Scalar>
class A {
  public:
    A (const Scalar z):
      z_(z)
    {
    }

    Scalar realPart()
    {
      return z_.real();
    }

  private:
    Scalar z_;
};

int main() {
  A<std::complex<double>> z0((1.0, 2.0));
  std::cout << z0.realPart() << std::endl; // check

  A<double> z1(1.0);
  std::cout << z1.realPart() << std::endl; // mööp
}
```

the compiler will complain at `z1.realPart()` because `double` doesn't know `.real()`.

How can I guard `.real()` at compile time?

Comment: what exactly do you want to happen with double ?

Comment: You can create template specialization for complex type.

Comment: @DavidHaim In case of `double`, just `return z_`, like you would expect mathematically.

Comment: so like @AkashPradhan said create a template specialization for it.

Comment: See stackoverflow template conditionals with type traits http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6251889/type-condition-in-template

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be done with a simple `is_complex` trait and SFINAE:

```c++
template<class T> struct is_complex : std::false_type {};
template<class T> struct is_complex<std::complex<T>> : std::true_type {};

template<class Scalar>
class A {
public:
    A(const Scalar z) : z_(z)
    { }

    template<class S = Scalar, std::enable_if_t<is_complex<S>{}>* = nullptr>
    Scalar realPart()
    {
      return z_.real();
    }

    template<class S = Scalar, std::enable_if_t<!is_complex<S>{}>* = nullptr>
    Scalar realPart()
    {
      return z_;
    }
private:
    Scalar z_;
};
```

Comment: Why is class S template argument needed? Could  not you use is_complex<Scalar>?

Comment: @Eugene The substitution failure has to occur within the *immediate context* of the template. The "outer" template of the entire class is not the immediate context of the member function template. So we use a dummy parameter to alias it.

Comment: After adding `#include <type_traits>` and `#include <complex>`, I'm getting `‘std::enable_if_t’ has not been declared`. This is with GCC 5.1.1. Is there something I forgot to add?

Comment: enable_if_t is c++14. it's equivalent to `typename std::enable_if<T>::type` - see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if