# Template specialization: ‘Scalar’ does not name a type

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14, template-specialization

I'm trying to implement a template specialization for `complex` scalars and, with [the help of Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30737105/353337), got to using `std::enable_if_t` and its poor man's version

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <complex>

// declarations
namespace Test {
  template<class Scalar>
    class A {
      public:
        A(const Scalar z);
        Scalar realPart();

      private:
        Scalar z_;
    };
}

// definitions
namespace Test {
  template<bool B, class T = void>
    using enable_if_t = typename std::enable_if<B,T>::type;
  template<class T> struct is_complex : std::false_type {};
  template<class T> struct is_complex<std::complex<T>> : std::true_type {};

  template<class Scalar>
    A<Scalar>::
    A(const Scalar z) : z_(z)
  { }

  template<class S = Scalar, enable_if_t<is_complex<S>{}>* = nullptr>
    Scalar
    A<Scalar>::realPart()
    {
      return z_.real();
    }

  template<class S = Scalar, enable_if_t<!is_complex<S>{}>* = nullptr>
    Scalar
    A<Scalar>::realPart()
    {
      return z_;
    }
}

int main() {
}
```

for C++11. The above code, separating declarations and definitions, however, fails to compile with

```
test4.cpp:29:22: error: ‘Scalar’ does not name a type
   template<class S = Scalar, enable_if_t<is_complex<S>{}>* = nullptr>
                      ^
```

It's not clear to me how this fails. Any hints?

Comment: Which is true, its a template parameter, always (in you example)

Comment: Hm, I don't quite understand. If removing the specialization in the definition, it compiles fine, so how does `Scalar` `not name a type`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this code:

```
template<class S = Scalar, enable_if_t<is_complex<S>{}>* = nullptr>
Scalar A<Scalar>::realPart()
{
  return z_.real();
}
```

`Scalar` doesn't name a type because it isn't one. That's just the name of a template parameter that you've been using. What you had intended to write was:

```
template<class Scalar, enable_if_t<is_complex<Scalar>{}>* = nullptr>
Scalar A<Scalar>::realPart()
{
  return z_.real();
}
```

However, this won't work either, since `A` doesn't have a second template non-type argument and you're trying to pass it one. What you're really trying to do is partially specialize the member function `A<Scalar>::realPart()` and that's impossible in the language.

What you need to do instead is dispatch to a helper that will know what to do. Something like:

```
template <class Scalar>
Scalar A<Scalar>::realPart() {
    return getRealPart(z_);
}
```

with:

```
template <typename Scalar>
Scalar getRealPart(Scalar r) { return r; }

template <typename Scalar>
Scalar getRealPart(std::complex<Scalar> c) { return c.real(); }
```

With a more complicated type trait, we'd do something like:

```
template <class Scalar>
Scalar A<Scalar>::realPart() {
    return getRealPart(z_, is_complex<Scalar>{});
}
```

And have overloads taking `true_type` and `false_type` as the second argument. In this particular case, that's unnecessary.

Comment: I see that this compiles, so great! It's a little nasty to have `std::complex<Scalar>` around if the specialization is `Scalar = std::complex<double>`, but I guess this doesn't hurt too bad.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a compiler at hand, but I think this:

```
template<class S = Scalar, enable_if_t<is_complex<S>{}>* = nullptr>
A<Scalar>::
Scalar realPart()
{
  return z_.real();
}
```

should be:

```
template<typename Scalar, enable_if_t<is_complex<Scalar>{}>* = nullptr>
//       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                         ^^^^^^
typename Scalar A<Scalar>::realPart()
//^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
{
  return z_.real();
}
```

... and the same for the other definition.