# Apply std::conj in template function if template argument is complex

Tags: c++, c++11, complex-numbers

**TL;DR** Let's say I have a function with a template argument `T` that takes a `std::vector<T>&` as input (see below), I want to conjugate this vector, if `T` is a complex type. How can I do that ?

**What I have tried** Following https://stackoverflow.com/a/30737105/5913047, I know I can check if a type is complex with

```cpp
template<class T> struct is_complex : std::false_type {};
template<class T> struct is_complex<std::complex<T>> : std::true_type {};
```

So I tried:

```cpp
template<typename T>
void MyFunction(std::vector<T>& MyVector){
    // do something
    if (is_complex<T>()){
       std::transform(MyVector.begin(), MyVector.end(), MyVector.begin(),[](T&c){return std::conj(c););
    }
}
```

but then, if I use this function with a non complex type, the compiler says that `conj` is not defined for non complex type. Is there some design to do what I want ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using an `if` statement. This requires the code in the `if` branch to be compilable, even if you don't need it to be executed.

In c++17, to conditionally *compile* a piece of code, you can use `if constexpr` like this:

```
if constexpr (is_complex<T>()) {
 //^^^^^^^^^   
    std::transform(MyVector.begin(), MyVector.end(), MyVector.begin(),[](T&c){ return std::conj(c); });
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/989vYv).

In c++11, you can use `std::enable_if` to write overloads for the case where the type is non-complex, like this:

```
template<typename T, typename std::enable_if<!is_complex<T>::value, int>::type = 0>
void MyFunction(std::vector<T>& MyVector){
    // do something
}

template<typename T,  typename std::enable_if<is_complex<T>::value, int>::type = 0>
void MyFunction(std::vector<T>& MyVector){
    // do something
    std::transform(MyVector.begin(), MyVector.end(), MyVector.begin(),[](T&c){ return std::conj(c); });
}
```

Here'a a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/d7W86T).