# How to evaluate Primitive vs Class templates at compilation time?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, templates, primitive-types

When we do ...

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T x)
{
   if (is_fundamental<T>::value)
   {
       ...
   } else
   {
     ...
   }
}
```

I would think that the `if` statement (as well as `is_fundamental<T>::value`) is evaluated at run time, is that right?

If yes, is there a way to make this evaluation at compilation time? I would like to have something like...

```
template <primitive_typename T>
void foo(T x)
{
   ...
}


template <noPrimitive_typename T>
void foo(T x)
{
   ...
}
```

One solution would be to overload every possible primitive type but it is not really a satisfying solution as it requires duplicating the code for primitive type many times. Is there no way to refer to all primitives with a a single typename?

Comment: Relevant if not duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6251889/type-condition-in-template

Comment: @StoryTeller Thanks for the link. The solution from the link implies overloading (template specialization) the function for each primitive type possible, is that right? This is not quite ideal. Is there no way to refer to all primitives with a typename?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In C++17 the `if constexpr` statement evaluates the condition at compile time and discards the branch that isn't selected:

```
if constexpr(std::is_fundamental_v<T>) {
    // do something with x
} else {
    // do something else with x
}
```

An old-fashioned way is to use tag dispatch:

```
template <typename FundamentalType>
void foo_helper(FundamentalType x, std::true_type);

template <typename NonFundamentalType>
void foo_helper(NonFundamentalType x, std::false_type);

template <typename T>
void foo(T x) {
    foo_helper(x, std::is_fundamental<T>{});
}
```

You can also use a partially specialized helper struct, but it's more code.

Answer (score 1):

What about tag dispatching?

```
template <typename T>
void fooHelper (T t, std::true_type const &)
 { /* true case */ }

template <typename T>
void fooHelper (T t, std::false_type const &)
 { /* false case */ }

template <typename T>
void foo (T t)
 { fooHelper(t, std::is_fundamental<T>{}); }
```